# Not able to fetch data through VBA script

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fetch data from a web page through VBA, but I am not able to fetch the data properly.

For example, if I need to fetch product description of any product which is under classname (a-section a-spacing-small), I need to provide many items on them. Please find below my code below:

```
strVal = doc.getElementsByClassName("a-section a-spacing-small").Item(0).innerText
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & rawno).Value = strVal
strVal = doc.getElementsByClassName("a-section a-spacing-small").Item(1).innerText
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & rawno).Value = strVal
strVal = doc.getElementsByClassName("a-section a-spacing-small").Item(2).innerText
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & rawno).Value = strVal
strVal = doc.getElementsByClassName("a-section a-spacing-small").Item(4).innerText
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & rawno).Value = strVal
strVal = doc.getElementsByClassName("a-section a-spacing-small").Item(5).innerText
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L" & rawno).Value = strVal
strVal = doc.getElementsByClassName("a-section a-spacing-small").Item(6).innerText
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M" & rawno).Value = strVal
strVal = doc.getElementsByClassName("a-section a-spacing-small").Item(7).innerText
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N" & rawno).Value = strVal
strVal = doc.getElementsByClassName("a-section a-spacing-small").Item(8).innerText
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O" & rawno).Value = strVal
strVal = doc.getElementsByClassName("a-section a-spacing-small").Item(9).innerText
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P" & rawno).Value = strVal
strVal = doc.getElementsByClassName("selection").Item(0).innerText
```

As you can see, I need to run all the code for product description.
The code which I need to fetch from web Page is contain under `<div id="productDescription" class="a-section a-spacing-small">`.
Product description is under `<div id="productDescription" class="a-section a-spacing-small">` in the website

Comment: Product description is under "<div id="productDescription" class="a-section a-spacing-small">" in web side

Comment: Have you tried using  a `For` loop to go through all of the items, instead of having to retype the code?

Comment: I don't know how to apply in this case because every field have some data how can i apply loop only for specific thing.

Comment: The actual problem with your question is that you didn't ask a question. Please be more precise about what your actually asking. You might benefit from reading [mcve] to improve your question. • Note that *"I am not able to fetch the data properly"* is no useful error description. Instead tell what your code actually does versus what you expected it to do, and/or which errors you get and where.

Comment: what's the website address? Which value specifically do you want?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am trying to express myself in better manner. URL for the product is https://www.amazon.in/2-oyss-Design-School-Supplies-Pieces/dp/B07GZWX71D/ref=sr_1_7?crid=1QKM8QEAR3M74&keywords=Stamps&qid=1572890121&refinements=p_85%3A10440599031&rnid=10440598031&rps=1&sprefix=Stamp%2Caps%2C370&sr=8-7. and i am trying to fetch the product description of this product. When i am try to fetch the data i had use the above code. but the problem is i am not able to fetch the data in one single code i have to run the all and then i need to find from that.

Comment: As i can check from the inspect my value which i need to fetch is under  "<div id="productDescription" class="a-section a-spacing-small">" this code. and now i am trying to fetch the data from the combination of both "GetElementbyID with GetElementByClassName" so that i can fetch only this value not the other classname value from the webside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't just target the p tag?

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1) = ie.document.querySelector("#productDescription p").innerText
```

Comment: Amazing buddy it's great.